# How to fetch data from SQL Server database when new row is inserted with restarting the fetch code?

Tags: python, sql-server

I am using Python 3.6 with 'pyodbc' library.

I have a database that inserts a new row every few seconds. The python code is a basic code that takes the newly inserted row by status id, the rest of the rows' status becomes 0.

```
import pyodbc

conn=pyodbc.connect("Driver={/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.5.so.1.1};""Server=XXXXXXXXX;""Database=XXXX;""uid=XXXX;pwd=XXXX")
cursor=conn.cursor()

sql = "select * from scriptDb where status=1"
cursor.execute(sql)   
data = cursor.fetchone()

print(data)
```

The above code runs just once and returns the last row, how to make it iterative so that whenever a new row is added it prints it.

Comment: SQL Server does not have a way to "push" updates to a client (except _maybe_ something with Service Broker, but you probably don't want to go there) AFAIK. Your app needs to poll for updates (the most basic implementation would be loop in your code with a delay) or have some method of being notified by whatever process is inserting those records. And please don't use `select *` in production code.

Comment: Your Python code should be polling at regular intervals to check for new rows; as @alroc has said, SQL Server won't push it out to you (unless you wanna start talking about triggers and endpoints :), but that'd be an entirely different question.  Please see the info [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Getting-started#select-basics), too, if you want to make sure your code iterates through all of the rows retrieved by cursor's (ugh) `select *` statement.     It appears, you're only working on the first result in the set.